# How to make a Person keep a reference to a Player in this code?

Tags: java, object, game-engine, modeling

Problem: When a skeleton enters a place, I want all the Players screens updated using this method in my `World` object:

```
/**
 * Say `text' in the Place `place'. The text will become visible at the
 * bottom of the text window of any Players currently watching `place'.
 * 
 * @param place
 *            The place where the string will be displayed.
 * @param text
 *            The string to be diplayed.
 */
public void sayAtPlace(Place place, String text) {
    synchronized (players) {
        Iterator<Player> ls = players.iterator();
        while (ls.hasNext()) {
            Player p = ls.next();
            if (p.currentPlace() == place) {
                p.say(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've got two classes, Person and Player and I want a Person to write to the textarea when the method `goTo` is called but I can't make the Person object have a proper reference to a Player that has the textarea:

```
package adventure;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * ADT for persons which is completed which subclasses to creating actors with
 * specific properties
 */
public class Person {
    public Player player = null;

    /**
     * Name of the Person.
     */
    public String name;

    /**
     * The World which this Person is associated with.
     */
    public World world;

    /**
     * Tells where this Person is at the moment.
     */
    public Place where;    


    /**
     * Create Person named `name' in world `world'.
     * 
     * @param world
     *            The world where the Person is created.
     * @param name
     *            Name of the Person.
     * @param app
     *            An image used to display the Person.
     */
    public Person(World world, String name, Image app) {
        this.world = world;
        this.name = name;
        this.appearance = app;
        // this.player = player;
        where = world.defaultPlace();
        where.enter(this);

        inventory = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<Thing>());
    }

    /**
     * Go directly, and quietly, to 'place'. That is to say, without posting a
     * message that you're doing so.
     * 
     * @param place
     *            A string referring to the Place to go to.
     * @see #goTo(Place)
     * @see #go
     */
    public void goTo(String place) {
        goTo(world.getPlace(place), null);
    }

    /**
     * Go directly, and quietly, to `whereTo'. That is to say, without posting a
     * message that you're doing so.
     * 
     * @param whereTo
     *            The Place to go to. Can be null in which case nothing happens.
     * @see #goTo(String)
     * @see #go
     */
    public void goTo(Place whereTo, Player player) {
        if (whereTo != null) {
            where.exit(this);
            whereTo.enter(this);
            // Update any Player's which are viewing place `where'.
            world.update(where);
            // Record our new position.
            where = whereTo;
            // Also update Player's here.
            world.update(where);
        }

        System.out.println("player:"+player);
        if(player != null){
            player.say("A terrifying skeleton warrior appears!");
        }
        // send a msg which doors are available
        Object[] doorNames = whereTo.exits.keySet().toArray();
        String s = "";
        int i = 1;
        for (Object obj : doorNames) {
            if (i < doorNames.length) {
                s = s + obj.toString().toLowerCase();

                if(i<doorNames.length){

                    s = s+ ",";
                }

            } if (i == doorNames.length && i > 1) {
                s = s + " and " + obj.toString().toLowerCase();
            }
            if (i == doorNames.length && i == 1) {
                s = obj.toString().toLowerCase();
            }
            ++i;
        }
        if (player != null) {
            player.say("There are doors " + s);
        }
    }



package adventure;

import java.awt.*;

/**
 * A Player object enables commands to control a certain person: »you». This
 * object is displayed graphically as a control panel where the user both can
 * control and follow the course of events
 */
public class Player extends Panel {
    private Person me;
    private PlaceView placeview;
    private Commands commands;
    private TextArea textarea;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Player, in World w, reflecting Person p.
     * 
     * @param w
     *            The world in which the Player will play in.
     * @param p
     *            The Person associated by Player.
     */
    Player(World w, Person p) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(650, 540);

        me = p;
        p.player = this;
        placeview = new PlaceView(me);
        commands = new Commands(me);
        textarea = new TextArea("", 10, 60, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
        textarea.append("You are in a dungeon. The horrible shrieks of the undead chill your bones.\n");
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        add("West", placeview);
        add("East", commands);
        add("South", textarea);
        w.addPlayer(this);
    }


    /**
     * Display a string in the players graphical interface.
     * 
     * @param text
     *            A string to display.
     */
    void say(String text) {
        textarea.append(text + '\n');
        textarea.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Place of the Person associated with the Player.
     * 
     * @return The Place of the Person associated with the Player.
     */
    public Place currentPlace() {
        return me.where;
    }
}
```

Do you understand what I'm trying to do? The code I want to work is

```
    System.out.println("player:"+player);
    if(player != null && this.name.equals("Skeleton")){
        player.say("A terrifying skeleton warrior appears!");
    }
```

But the player reference of the Person that is a zombie is not instanciated. The only Person who has a Player object instanciated is the Player that is also a Person.

Can you help me? I also posted the full versions of the Person, Player and World classes here

http://pastebin.com/RJCcr2ph (Person)
http://pastebin.com/eYSh8L9Q (Player)
http://pastebin.com/DKvRvEY8 (World)

Comment: this.player is never used in your Person constructor, is this normal?

Comment: Can you please shorten the program to just contain enough to show the problem?

Comment: @Adel Boutros You're right this is the problem. If I could instanciate the Player in the Person contructor then the problem would be solved. But when I make a Person I don't have the Player. I need to couple the object somehow.

Comment: @Keppil I've shortened it and I can also include links to pastebin.com where I can paste the full versions of the classes.

Comment: Your approach is not logical, how can you create a Player who is not a person? I think you need to redesign your entities

Comment: Your `Person` class has a `Player` reference and vice versa, it is never a good sign if that is needed. I think you need to try to clean up your class hierarchy.

Comment: @Keppil You are absolutely right. I've removed the Player reference since it is not a one-to-one relation. In fact multiplayer should work and now I found the method that I should use for a ´Place` in my `World` that updates all the players's screens so I just need to call that every time a skeleton goes to a place, so my problem is fairly simple to understand and I think we can make it work today if I check into more of the surrounding code that I inherited from a game project at my university, updating it and adding functionality so that I can have a nice adventure game.

Comment: @Adel Boutros For this game a `Player` is a `Panel` and a `Person` is an Object. I removed the `Player`reference from the Person class, it was wrong. Player is a viewer of the game and there could be many players and a player is a person and there is only one player at this time but it should be programmable to multi-player as well: please check the Adventure contructor where object are created: `Person me = new Person(world, "You", null); player = new Player(world, me);` so the Player IS a Person.

Comment: I'm testing it now that it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to have 2 classes in which each class has a reference to the other. What you need is to create one of them (let it be `Foo`), create the other class (let it be `Boo`) and pass a reference of `Foo` to it via the constructor, and then set a reference of `Boo` inside `Foo` class via setter method.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Boo b = new Boo(f);
    f.setBoo(b);
}

class Foo
{
    private Boo b;

    public Foo()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void setBoo(Boo b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class Boo
{
    private Foo f;

    public Boo(Foo f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

Now, `Foo` has a reference of `Boo`, and `Boo` has a reference of `Foo` :)

Comment: If you read the comments on the question, he said the instance of class Foo is not know at the time of creation of the instance of class Boo. thus, he can't pass the reference in the constructor

Comment: @AdelBoutros then he could do the opposite. One of them should exist before creating the other.

Answer (score 1):

First , you should instantiate the Person's member 'player' in the constructor .

```
this.player = new Player(world, this);
```

Then , change the code from

```
public void goTo(String place) {
    goTo(world.getPlace(place), null);
}
```

to

```
public void goTo(String place) {
    goTo(world.getPlace(place), this.player);
}
```